# Field validation applies to all the component within the ui:repeat

Tags: ajax, primefaces, jsf-2.2

i'm using JSF 2.2.8 and primefaces 6.0 and I'm trying to update an element in my form. When i run my XHTML everything is displayed correctly but unfortunately when I start to input data in the input fileds it does'nt let me input data and the input mask is applied to each input and by displaying a message you must indicate a value and the fields are not required

Here is the screen of my view 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOtBh.jpg

and here is the code which causes the problem

```
    <h:form>
    <ui:repeat  value="#{etpBean.affectations}" var="affectation">
        <ui:repeat var="activite" value="#{etpBean.activites}">
          <p:inputText value="#{etpBean.getValeurActivite(affectation,activite).etp}">
             <p:ajax listener="#{etpBean.onControleChange(affectation)}" process="@this" update=":#{p:component('controle1')}" event="blur" />
               </p:inputText>
         </ui:repeat>
        <ui:repeat var="projet" value="#{etpBean.projet}">
          <p:inputText value="#{etpBean.getValeurActivite(affectation,projet).etp}">
             <p:ajax listener="#{etpBean.onControleChange(affectation)}" process="@this" update=":#{p:component('controle1')}" event="blur" />
               </p:inputText>
         </ui:repeat>
      <h:outputText id="controle1" value="#{affectation.message}"/>                                             
    </ui:repeat
    </h:form>
```

I tried to add the process in  but it does not work.And what I do not understand why the validation is triggered while I have not yet submit the form.

Comment: I don't see any validation in you code.. nor any inputmask. [mcve] please

Comment: @Kukeltje that is the problem i don't have validation in my code and i dont have inputmask. You can look the image

Comment: update ur question question for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an implicit #{component} object in the EL scope that evaluates to the current UI component.

try this

```
<p:ajax listener="#{etpBean.onControleChange(affectation)}" process="@this" update=":#{p:component('controle')}" event="blur" />
```

Comment: Can you please add an explanation on why this works and what the error is in the original question. That way others can more easily learn from it.